# Sustainsys.Saml2 with IdentityServer3 with Okta as IdP

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver3, okta, owin-middleware, sustainsys-saml2

I'm looking at the Sustainsys.Saml2 samples and I've found that if I point the SampleMvcApplication to use Okta as an IdP that all the relevant claims are created. However if I use Okta as an external IdP for the SampleIdentityServer3 project I only see the openid claims. Is there a wat to configure IdentityServer to pass all the claims in the Saml token back to the client app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if this works in your exact scenario however I'm using the following approach to return a collection of required Claims, to the clients, in the token (noting that I'm using Identity Server 4).

You can add the `profile` scope the the request from the client.

Then you can make a request to the User Info Endpoint:

`options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;`

In your implementation of `public async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)` you can add in whichever claims you wish.

Alternatively, you can set `AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true` in your Client Config then can get the claims in your token.  *Be weary about including too many claims in your token which can result in it getting too large for some browsers to work with*.

Docs: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/profileservice.html

I also found this article helpful: https://leastprivilege.com/2017/11/15/missing-claims-in-the-asp-net-core-2-openid-connect-handler/